# Searching on one table with multiple parameters query

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables such as below:

Table 1 contain `UserID` and `Name` while table 2 contain `UserID`, `Skill_ID`, and `SkillName`

What I want to do is, I want to search someone who has 2 skill, searched via SkillName.

example: I have *Andy* as `Name` where he have 2 skill *PHP* and *C#* so when i Search *PHP* & *C#*, Andy will be shown as result.

Can anybody help me? Thank you.

Comment: 1. Normalise your data. You need a table for users, a table for skills, and a table (user_skills) that relates one to the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT a.Name
FROM    table1 a
        INNER JOIN table2 b
            ON a.userID = b.user_ID
WHERE   b.skill_name IN ('PHP','C#')
GROUP   BY a.Name
HAVING  COUNT(*) = 2
```

the design of your table is not well normalized. The type of relationship is `Many-to-Many` and in this case, this should be three tables, `Users`, `Skills` and the linking table `User_Skills`.

A suggested design would be:

Table `User`

- UserID  (PK)
- Name

Table `Skills`

- SkillID  (PK)
- SkillName

Table `User_Skills`

- UserID  (FK)
- SkillID (FK)

Comment: You will need `COUNT(DISTINCT SkillName)` instead of `COUNT(*)` if `(userID, SkillName)` are not guaranteed to be unique.  Also, it's probably worth mentioning that the presence of `Skill_ID` and `SkillName` in `Table2` is a violation of [2NF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_normal_form).

Comment: that looks good, i will try it later, if i find another problem i will ask here. thanks for your help